# Choose Scaling for t

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, dimensional-analysis

**My question is the last part of the d) part of the exercise 1.17** in Mark Holms' Introduction to Applied Mathematics. The exercise is given below, where I have emphasized the part of it that is my question.

**1.17.** A thermodynamic model for the concentration $u$ and temperature $q$ of a mixture consists of the following equations( Gray and Scott [1994])

$\frac{\text{d}u}{\text{d}t}=k_1-k_2ue^{k_3q}$,

$\frac{\text{d}q}{\text{d}t}=k_4ue^{k_3q}-k_5q$.

The initial conditions are $u=0$ and $q=0$ at $t=0$.

(a) What are the dimensions of the $k_i$'s?

(b) Explain why the rule of thumb for scaling used in the projectile problem does not help here

(c) Find the steady-state solution, that is, the solution of the differential equations with $u'=0$ and $q'=0$

(d) Nondimensionalize the problem using the steady-state solution from (c) to scale $u$ and $q$. **Make sure to explain how you selected the scaling for $t$**

Please note that this is not homework, but part of a self-study.

---

Suggested solution (shown only for (d)):

Result from (c):

$q_{\text{eq}}=\frac{k_4k_1}{k_2k_5}$

$u_{\text{eq}}=\frac{k_1}{k_2}e^{-\frac{k_3k_4k_1}{k_2k_5}}$

To do the scaling I first need to make a change of variables:

$u=u_cu^*$

$q=q_cq*$

$t=t_ct^*$

By using the chain rule, we get that the system of the ODEs becomes:

$\frac{u_c}{t_c}\frac{\text{d}u*}{\text{d}t*}=k_1-k_2u_cu^*e^{k_3q_cq^*}$

$\frac{q_c}{t_c}\frac{\text{d}q*}{\text{d}t*}=k_4u_cu^*e^{k_3q_cq^*}-k_5q_cq^*$

Then we need to form dimensionless groups of the parameters in the ODEs. We get that:

$\frac{u_c}{k_1t_c}\frac{\text{d}u*}{\text{d}t*}=1-\frac{k_2}{k_1}u_cu^*e^{k_3q_cq^*}$

$\frac{1}{k_5t_c}\frac{\text{d}q*}{\text{d}t*}=\frac{k_4u_cu^*}{k_5q_c}e^{k_3q_cq^*}-q^*$

so that the dimensionless independent groups are:

$\Pi_1=\frac{1}{k_5t_c}$

$\Pi_2=\frac{k_4u_c}{k_5q_c}$

$\Pi_3=\frac{u_c}{k_1t_c}$

$\Pi_4=\frac{k_2}{k_1}u_c$

$\Pi_5=k_3q_c$

We know that we should choose $u_c=u_{\text{eq}}$ and $q_c=q_{\text{eq}}$. 
For $t_c$ I see 3) possible solutions:

1) Find the time it takes for the solution, starting with $q=0, u=0$ at $t=0$ to reach $u_{\text{eq}}$ and $q_{\text{eq}}$

2) Set $\Pi_1=1$

3) Set $\Pi_3=1$

To use 1), we need to solve the system of ODEs, so we do **not** use 1). We are then left with 2) and 3). Choosing between 2) and 3) is choosing which of the terms $\frac{\text{d}q*}{\text{d}t*}$ and $\frac{\text{d}u*}{\text{d}t*}$ is the most important. If for instance I set $\Pi_1=1$, then $\frac{\text{d}q*}{\text{d}t*}$  is the most important term of the two mentioned.

Is my argumentation correct?